# Get the latest record date base

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have structure in database

```
 Inside   DateTime                    VehNo
  0      2014-06-03 10:51:36           1
  1      2014-06-03 09:13:57           1
  0      2014-06-03 10:35:38           2
  1      2014-06-03 10:40:38           2
```

and i want output like this base on DateTime

```
 Inside   DateTime                    VehNo
  0      2014-06-03 10:51:36           1     
  1      2014-06-03 10:40:38           2
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want the **most recent** entry for each separate `VehNo` (or `Inside`??) value - right? You should say what you really want! Don't just dump a pile of records on us and assume we know what you mean!

Comment: basically inside is a status field i want vehno with latest status base on date time and in this query two tables are involve one is vehicle and another is date time with status.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming columns Inside and VehNo are unique:

```
    SELECT inside, MAX([datetime]) as latest_datetime, vehno
    FROM mytable
GROUP BY inside, vehno;
```

Assuming only VehNo is unique:

```
WITH max_date AS (
  SELECT max([datetime]) as max_datetime, vehno FROM mytable GROUP BY vehno
)
SELECT m.* FROM mytable m
INNER JOIN max_date md ON m.[datetime] = md.max_datetime AND m.vehno = md.vehno;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Inside,
           DateTime,
           VehNo,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY Inside ORDER BY DateTime DESC) RN
    FROM <TableName>     
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: See the comment by `enigma` to my comment - he wants the more recent row for each `VehNo` so you should use `PARTITION BY VehNo`

Comment: Yes, If you want vehno with latest status, then 
PARTITION BY VehNo

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.Inside,T2.DateTime,T2.VehNo
FROM TableName T1 JOIN
    (SELECT MAX([DateTime]) as [DateTime],VehNo
     FROM TableName
     GROUP BY VehNo) T2 
   ON T1.DateTime=T2.DateTime AND T1.VehNo=T2.VehNo
ORDER BY T2.VehNo
```

Example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dee49/3).

**Explanation:**

Here we are selecting maximum value of `datetime` for each `VehNo`. Then we join this result with the table itself for fetching the respective `Inside`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last DateTime for every VehNo, and Inside option this should be your query:

```
SELECT M.Inside, 
       M.DateTime, 
       M.VehNo 
FROM   mytable M 
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(DateTime) as max_date, 
                   Inside, 
                   VehNo  
            FROM mytable T 
            GROUP BY 
                     VehNo, Inside) 
ON M.Inside = T.Inside 
AND M.DateTime = T.max_date
AND M.VehNo = T.VehNo
```